# What is an Elite card in Hearthstone?

Tags: terminology, hearthstone

You can divide Hearthstone cards by mechanics, by class, by type, by set(basic, expert etc...), by rarity etc...
But I couldn't find what is an Elite card? For example Leeroy Jenkins is an elite card.

Can somebody explain?

Thanks.

Comment: Leeroy is a Legendary card, there is no such thing as an elite card as far as I know.

Comment: I found this link: http://hearthstonejson.com/#individualSets it says Leeroy is an elite cards. Just to ask I was confused. Rarity of the cards can be recognized by color of the gem stone in the middle of the card

Comment: The guy says, he extracted the data from a hearthstone system file

Comment: perhaps "Elite" is a competitive term for Legendary cards that are actually good?

Comment: There is no in game use of the term elite. Since the question is about a term which can only be found in game files (data which is, I add, not supposed to be available), this is speculating on developer intent.

Comment: mm ok, whatever. It doesn't matter. I will delete the question

Comment: www.hearthpwn.com/cards lets you filter by elite, and based on my observation, it looks like elite is roughly synonymous with legendary as far as playable cards go. My guess is it is the developer attribute that specifies whether you are only allowed to have 1 copy or 2 in a deck.

Comment: @jw013 Seems reasonable. The only two non-elite legends are Ashbringer and the Jaraxxus Hero- neither of which can be included in decks anyway.

Comment: @Studoku What about a certain Tauren Chieftain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jw013 is correct.  An elite card is one that you can only have one copy of in a deck.  As the game currently stands, all elite cards are legendary rarity, and all legendary rarity cards are elite, however in a future update it is possible they may add an elite card that is non-legendary, or a legendary card that can have two copies and is thus not elite, since the elite label is a separate piece of code from the legendary rarity label.